# Replace variables from .tpl file

Tags: php, templates

### Situation at this moment

I'm using this function:

```
public function fetch($file){        
    $file = $this->options['template_dir'].(string)$file;

    if(file_exists($file)){
        ob_start();
        if($this->options['extract']){
            extract($this->vars);
        }
        include $file;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }else{
        throw new Exception('De ('.$file.') template bestaat niet.');
    }        
}
```

Basically it just replaces `<?php echo $name; ?>` from the tpl with the data of `$tpl->name`.

### The question

I would like to start using `{$name}` instead of using `<?php echo $name; ?>` in my TPL files. Can anyone point me in the right direction for replacing this with the data of `$tpl->name`?

### What I've tried

I tried to do it with a regex, trying to find the { and } and then replace it, but it will only output `$name` as text.

Comment: I did this many years ago but I'm sure that you have to use a flag like **e** to exec the regex result. I'll search a bit :)

Comment: @Joran, there are multiple things that use the file extension `tpl` in PHP alone, not to mention all the other languages.  It is not an appropriate tag.  Please stop recreating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably go with a regex, but here is an alternate.  You could also foreach through $this->vars keys:

```
$template = file_get_contents($file);
$vars     = explode(',', '{$'.implode('},{$', array_keys($this->vars)).'}');
$output   = str_replace($vars, $this->vars, $template);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
preg_replace("/\{(.+)\}/e", "$1", $template);
```

note that is deprecated from 5.5 as said on php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php